# Get the cell of the next column with vba

Tags: vba, cell, offset

I can't solve my vba problem. I need your help.
I would like to get the cell in the next column.
if Loulou =A3, i would like plage1 = B3
If loulou =A5, i would like plage 1 = B5

```
Dim Loulou As String  
Dim plage1 As String  
Loulou = Cells(Int(Rnd * 20) + 1, 1).Select  
plage1 = Cells(Loulou, 1)
```

I tried different things, to put offset on a variable, but it does not work.
Thank you for you help

Comment: `Dim Loulou As Long: Loulou = Cells(Int(Rnd * 20) + 1, 1).Row: plage1 = Cells(Loulou,2)`

Comment: Thank you for you help but it does not seem to work

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by it does not work.

Comment: You did not define the plage1's type. i dont understand the .row at the end of Cells(Int(Rnd * 20) + 1, 1).Row:

Comment: If you want to retrieve the value of column B of `Loulou` then you can keep it as `String` (provided that the cell value is a string). `Row` property returns the row number of the randomly selected cell. Perhaps you should explain exactly what do you want to achieve with the code - Are you looking to get the value of the cell in column A? You simply want the `Range` object of the cell in Column A?  @dataS

Comment: ok thank you for your help.
at the end, i woud like to have a msgbox with a random cell where are stored my questions(loulou: it's working) and a second msgbox with the answers (plage1 with the next cell: its not working yet)

Comment: FaneDuru's answer should get you there then, please refer to it and accept his answer once it address your question. @dataS

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testNextColVal()
  Dim Loulou As Range, plage1 As Range
  Set Loulou = Cells(Int(Rnd * 20) + 1, 1)
  Set plage1 = Loulou.Offset(, 1)
  Debug.Print plage1.Address, plage1.Value
  MsgBox Plage1.Address & " - " & plage1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, its working :) 
What "Debug.Print plage1.Address, plage1.Value" does it mean?

Comment: @dataS Please, press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE (Visual Basic for Applications Editor) and the necessary window will be shown. It is good to use it when try debugging... I thought you know it. I will adapt the above code to also return in a message box... Did it.

Comment: i am making my firsts steps in vba. thanks a lot for your help